# DST hour from local timezone DB using JDK8

Tags: java, time, java-8, dst

I am using JDK8 zonedatetime to get the DST rules e.g:

```
ZoneId zoneIdTmp = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = rules.nextTransition(Instant.now());
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
2016-11-06T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

DST switches at 2am (back to 1am) on Nov 6th.  I am assuming the 1:00 am time in the output above points to the new time after the DST change and the 5:00 points to the new offset from UTC.  I have checked my local timezone database

```
zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York
```

the output there displays the (approx) 2am time

```
Sun Nov  6 05:59:59 2016 UT = Sun Nov  6 01:59:59 2016 EDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
```

Instead of adding any logic myself from the JDK output, is there a way for me to get the 2am time from the ZoneDateTime (or a reliably working logic that works across different zone IDs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you output the rule? With toString()? If you use the getters there is all kind of information which looks like what you are after, especially [`ZoneOffsetTransition.getOffsetBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html) and `getOffsetAfter()` in combination with `getInstant()` or `getDateTimeAfter()`.

Comment: thanks it was a toString() ouput (System.out.println) to see what values I had

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to get the required information using **ZoneOffsetTransition's getDateTimeBefore()** method to fetch the transition time for DST.  The output for America/New_York from the next ZoneOffsetTransition is copied below and is what I was looking for:

```
2016-11-06T02:00
```